# how to convert object array to string array?

Tags: object, collections, hashmap

I have changed hashmap into collection,collection into object,now I need object into String.either this way or any better way than this would be really appreciable.

```
Collection<String> t;
        Collection<String> n;
        String[] names;
        String[] types;
        Object[] foo;
        Object[] doo;
  HashMap<Integer, String> typehashmap=new HashMap<Integer, String>();
           HashMap<Integer, String> namehashmap=new HashMap<Integer, String>();

      t= typehashmap.values();
      n= namehashmap.values();

        foo=t.toArray();
        doo=n.toArray();
      for(int i=0;i<t.size();i++){
 error-->           types[i]=(String) foo[i];
  error-->               names[i]=(String) doo[i];
      }
```

Comment: It would be very helpful if you also tagged your question with the programming language it refers to. And maybe you should tell us what's wrong with the code ;-)

Comment: Runtime error or compiler error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the "error" is an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException", you need to allocate the arrays before you add anything to them. There is also another toArray method that can help:

```
String[] types = typehashmap.values().toArray(new String[typehashmap.size()]);
```

Comment: I was trying this before too may be I was wrong somewhere.thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Just use HashMap.values().toArray() eg:

```
String[] names = namehashmap.values().ToArray(new String[namehashmap.size()]);
String[] types = typehashmap.values().ToArray(new String[typehashmap.size()]);
```

Comment: that would yield array of objects .still left with the same issue.how to convert object array into String array

Comment: I am already done with this approach .getting compile time error.at the above mentioned lines.even tried casting

Answer (score 0):

It may be a compiler error! You don't initialize the types array and names array before you use them. And the first floor's method is good way for solving the problem.